# Codeigniter and memory allocation issue for mysqli

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a HUGE DB and when I'm trying to retrive some information in order to create a PDF and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 128 bytes) in 
.../system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_result.php on line 167
```

Is there a way to increase the memory limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

**ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');**

Comment: Now it gives `134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 82 bytes)`

Comment: Ok, if I set it this way `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` it basically removes the default limit. Tks for your help!

Comment: Where do you do that? Your answer is not an explanation..

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the limit like below :-

```
ini_set("memory_limit","24M");
```